# Collatz Conjecture: Am I understanding the Chain Equation from Simons & de Weger (2005) correctly? Is this inequality valid?

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, proof-explanation, collatz-conjecture

I was thinking through the Chain Equation from [this paper](https://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) by Simons & de Weger on the [Collatz Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

The Chain Equation is an equation which is only true if a nontrivial cycle (a cycle other than $1, 4, 2,  1, \dots, 1, 4, 2, 1$) exists.

I was attempting to restate the equation as a simpler inequality. I reached a conclusion that appears to me to be incorrect.  I am unable to find my mistake.

**Let**:

- $n$ be a natural number.
- $T(n) = \begin{cases}
  \frac{1}{2}(3n + 1), && \text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\
  \frac{1}{2}n, && \text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
  \end{cases}$
- *sequence* be an increasing subsequence of odd integers followed by a decreasing subsequence of even integers
- a *cycle* be an $m$-*cycle* if it consists of $m$ sequences with a total of $K$ odd numbers and a total of $L$ even numbers.
- a *non-trivial* cycle be any cycle that contains natural numbers greater than $2$.
- a sequence is *periodic* if there exists an integer $p \ge 1$ in the sequence $\{ n, T(n), T^2(n), \dots, T^{p}(n) \}$ where:

  - $T^0(n) = n$
  - $T^{i+1}(n) = T(T^i(n))$
  - $T^p(n) = n$
- $t_0, t_1, \dots, t_{m-1}$ be the indices of the $m$ local minima in an $m$-cycle such that:

  - $t_0 = 0$
  - $t_0 < t_1 < t_2 < \dots < t_{m-1} < p$
- $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_{m-1}$ be the indices of the $m$ local maxima in an $m$-cycle such that:

  - $t_0 < s_0 < t_1 < s_1 < \dots < t_{m-1} < s_{m-1} \le p-1$
- $x_i, y_i$ be the values of the local minima and maxima so that:

  - $x_i = T^{t_i}(n)$
  - $y_i = T^{s_i}(n)$
- $k_i, l_i$ be defined so that:

  - $k_i = s_i - t_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, m-1$
  - $l_i = t_{i+1} - s_i$ for $i = 0, \dots, m-2$ and $l_{m-1} = p + t_0 - s_{m-1}$
  - $K = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}k_i$
  - $L = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}l_i$

Here's the statement of the **Chain Equation** (2.1) on page 56:

$$3^{k_i}a_i - 1 = 2^{k_{i+1} + l_i}a_{i+1} - 2^{l_i}$$

Here's my restatement of the **Chain Equation** as an inequality:

(1)  $3^{k_i}a_i + 2^{l_i} = 2^{k_{i+1}+l_i}a_{i+1} + 1$

(2)  $3^{k_i}a_i + 2^{l_i} > 2^{k_{i+1}+l_i}a_{i+1}$

(3)  $\left(\dfrac{3^{k_i}}{2^{l_i}}\right)a_i + 1 > 2^{k_{i+1}}a_{i+1}$

(4)  $\left(\dfrac{3^{k_i}}{2^{l_i}}\right)a_i \ge 2^{k_{i+1}}a_{i+1}$

Step (4) appears to me to be unreasonable.

Am I understanding the chain equation correctly?  Did I make a mistake in one of my steps?

Comment: With $\frac{3^{k_i}a_i - 1}{2^{l_i}} = 2^{k_{i+1}}a_{i+1} - 1$ you should have $\frac{3^{k_i}}{2^{l_i}}a_i+(1-\frac{1}{2^{l_i}}) = 2^{k_{i+1}}a_{i+1}$ or $\frac{3^{k_i}}{2^{l_i}}a_i < 2^{k_{i+1}}a_{i+1}$ since $l_i>0$

Comment: Thanks very much!  That really helps!

Comment: So step (4) is wrong because I am assuming that all values are integers but they are not!  :-). Got it!

Comment: Step (3) is correct (you would have to remove a small value $\frac{1}{2^{l_i}}$ from LHS to get the the RHS, so LHS is bigger), but indeed, you can't have an integer if you multiply a power of 3 with an odd number and then divide by a power of 2.